# how to write output channel from itemWriter in spring batch and spring integration?

Tags: spring, ftp, spring-integration

firstly thanks for attention, i combined spring batch and spring integration, i defined a job flow and retrieve files from ftp adapter and sent to jobChannel, and process on it with spring batch , i want to write to output channel and consume the channel after processing, my code is:

```
     <int-ftp:outbound-gateway id="gatewayGET"
                                  local-directory-expression="'./backup/' +#remoteDirectory"
                                  session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
                                  request-channel="toGetChannel"
                                  reply-channel="toProcessChannel"
                                  command="get"
                                  temporary-file-suffix=".writing"
                                  command-options="-P"
                                  expression="payload.remoteDirectory + '/' + payload.filename"/>
        <int:channel id="toProcessChannel">
            <int:interceptors>
                <int:wire-tap channel="logger2"/>
            </int:interceptors>
        </int:channel>
    <int:channel id="outboundJobRequestChannel"/>
    <int:channel id="replyJobChannel"/>
   <service-activator input-channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel"/>
 <int:transformer input-channel="toProcessChannel" output-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel">
        <bean class="ir.isc.macna.configuration.FileMessageToJobRequest">
            <property name="fileParameterName" value="fileName"/>
        </bean>
    </int:transformer>
    <batch-int:job-launching-gateway request-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel"
                                     reply-channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel"/>
```

and my writer code is:

```
@Component
@StepScope
public class MacnaFileWriter implements ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter<FileInfo> {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("replyJobChannel")
    private MessageChannel messageChannel;
    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends FileInfo> list) throws Exception {

       // send Message to replyJobChannel channel with Send method
    }
}
```

and use ftp adapter to write files on the server:

```
<int-ftp:outbound-gateway session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
                              request-channel="replyJob"
                              command="mput"
                              auto-create-directory="true"
                              expression="payload"
                              remote-directory-expression="payload.remoteDirectory + '/' + payload.filename + '.out'"
                              reply-channel="output"/>
```

Is this standard way to run batch job and consume result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MessageChannel` has `send` method. For this purpose you can use `MessageBuilder` to create a `Message<?>` for your `payload`.

Since it is just a `<channel>` there is no difference with any other `MessageChannel` to consume. The standard way define a consumer like this:

```
<service-activator input-channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel"/>
```

However it isn't clear why you are going to send messages to the `jobLaunchReplyChannel`, when this channel is specific for the result from  `<batch-int:job-launching-gateway>` (`JobLaunchingGateway` class):

```
jobExecution = this.jobLaunchingMessageHandler.launch(jobLaunchRequest);
```

So, that `jobExecution`  is sent to the `jobLaunchReplyChannel`.

See [Spring Batch Integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html) Documentation.

Maybe do you need `AsyncItemWriter` or `ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter`?

Comment: thanks for reply @Artem, i want to retrieve files from ftp server and run batch job , and again write the files on the ftp server with mput commad , thanks for help me to understand `jobLaunchReplyChannel` that's how it work, i need other channel to send message, Now I'll update the post.

Comment: Yes, that looks good. You really can just send each item to some `MessageChannel` as I said in my answer. And see this question for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033484/how-does-chunkmessagechannelitemwriter-collect-replies-in-spring-batch-remote-ch

Comment: really thanks for attention and answer to my question.